How to determine the correct direction of the transformer winding (photo)
I'm winding a transformer for a DAB converter.

Image link (MDPI - A DAB Converter with Common-Point-Connected Winding Transformers Suitable for a Single-Phase 5-Level SST System): https://www.mdpi.com/1996-1073/11/4/928
I wound half of the primary winding, then I will wind the secondary and wind the rest of the primary winding on top.

My photo.
Can you check if I chose the correct winding direction for the secondary winding compared to the primary? The blue and black dots indicates the beginning of the winding. This point is not entirely clear, perhaps you can clarify this. Thank you!

Your primary winding is connected to your circuit via wires (it seems) so, once you have decided where your secondary winding wires terminate, you can do a little test with a signal generator and an oscilloscope.
If the secondary output is in phase with the primary applied voltage you can say where the dots are because, this is what the dots signify. If you find that the output is 180° out of phase with the applied primary voltage then swap the primary wires over.
You can do this because the wires appear to make floating connections to your PCB.
Alternatively, just take a guess and try it out but make sure your output capacitor is non-polarized. The worst that can happen is that your DC output voltage is inverted.
Regarding you photograph, the dot information is correct but, given that your secondary winding wire-ends are not visible, it's of little use as a guide.

Got it, your answer solved my question. Thank you very much!
